# Optional reference field in app engine datastore

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a model

```
class MyModel(ndb.Model):
    foo = ndb.StringProperty()

class OtherModel(ndb.Model):
    baz = ndb.StringProperty()
    ref = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=MyModel)
```

I built a view where I can create and modify these model entities and I would like the `ref` field of `OtherModel` to be optional but when I try to submit and empty `ref` field or remove the old value of it I got an error of the `ndb.KeyProperty`'s validation

My updating logic looks like this:

```
for property in editableProperties:
    # Lets suppose this parses values from a form in a request to the needed type
    new_value = deserialize(property._kind, self.request.get(property._name))
    setattr(item, property._name, new_value)
```

Where I tried setting the new_value to `None` and empty string. How can I make possible to do this?

Comment: Please include the full error message.  Also, try simpler updating logic for debugging purposes: `item.ref = new_value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't have a `Model` entity key to set the `ref` property to just do not set it - i.e. do not include that property in the entity value that you're passing back to the datastore for writing. If you do, the property value you're passing will be subjected to sanity checks and they'll fail.

In other words: do not do at all

```
`setattr(item, property._name, new_value)`
```

for `ref` when `new_value` is not a key. Instead do something along these lines:

```
if hasattr(item, property._name):
   delattr(item, property._name)
```

Comment: Thank you it worked as expected. I couldn't find an example of this anywhere.